# Как поменять имя загружаемой фотографии на латинское?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, такой код, чтобы постоянно менял имя загружаемой в базу фотографии на латинское и чтобы, конечно, они каждый раз были разные. Через форму попадает в обработчик переменная, допустим, foto, в ней фотография с русским названием, а дальше что?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать массив, где ключами будут русские буквы, а значениями - латинские:

```
$array = array(
    'буква'=>'bukva',
    'буква2'=>'bukva2'

)
```

Comment: Не выполняется условие:

>и чтобы, конечно, они каждый раз были разные

Comment: Ну и добавить фазу луны, число и время с точностью до секунд....

Answer (score 1):

Можно в качестве имени использовать уникальное цифровое значение: md5, sha1 от имени и фазы луны, ID записи в базе... В первом случае проверять есть ли в базе такое, если есть - менять фазу луны и генерить заново. Во втором - делать апдейт по insert_id().

Comment: Извините, я пока не очень хорошо разбираюсь в php, насчет ID записи в базе, напишите, пожалуйста, подробнее.